# read all the elements of an enum in a file using ksh

Tags: shell, sed, enums

Need to read all the elements from an enum.  Suppose enum.txt has following entry

```
YesOrNo ::= INTEGER {
yes(0),
no(1),
unknown(2)
}
EnOrDis ::=  INTEGER {
enable(0),
disable(1),
unknown(2)
}
```

Now I can easily grep YesOrNo from enum.txt by grep -w -i YesOrNo enum.txt
But I need to read the elements of that enum YesOrNo.
I tried to get elements between '{' and '}' to result.txt.

```
start_line = $(grep -i -w -n YesOrNo enum.txt)
end_line = $(grep -A 10 -w -i YesOrNo enum.txt | grep -w -n -m1 } enum.txt)
sed -n '$start_line,$end_linep' enum.txt > result.txt
```

but i am not getting the end_line as -A and -m option is not supported to my sun solaris.
Please let me know any other way to read between that two curly braces i.e, { ,}.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the curly braces are not on the same lines as the enum elements:

```
enum="YesOrNo"
sed -n "/$enum *::=/,/}/ {/[{}]/!p}" enum.txt
```

```
yes(0),
no(1),
unknown(2)
```

If you're doing that at a shell prompt, you may need to `set +H` so the `!` doesn't trigger a history expansion

Comment: How about this: 
sed -e '1,/YesOrNo ::=/d' -e '/}/,$d' enum.txt> result.txt

Comment: that may not work if YesOrNo is the first line (at least it didn't for me, GNU sed). try `sed -e '0,/YesOrNo ::=/d' -e '/}/,$d' enum.txt`